# Saving polygon coordinates using google maps to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to save some polygon coordinates using google maps DrawingManager to a Postgres database in my Rails application. I have successful managed to display polygon and coordinates, but when I save the project all i get in my db row for the coordinates is `" "`.

I'm using a json column in my table. I'm not sure if this is the best method.

**Javascript**

```
function initMap() {
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
 center: { lat: -30.2266, lng: 149.4455 },
 zoom: 8
});
        
 var polyOptions = {
  strokeWeight: 0,
  fillOpacity: 0.45,
  editable: true,
  draggable: true 
 };

 var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
  drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
  drawingControlOptions: {
  position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
    drawingModes: ["polygon"]
  },
 markerOptions: {
  draggable: true
 },
 polylineOptions: {
  editable: true,
  draggable: true
 }
});
 google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function (e) {
  if (e.type !== google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER) {
    drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);
    var newShape = e.overlay;
    newShape.type = e.type;
    google.maps.event.addListener(newShape, 'click', function (e) {
      if (e.vertex !== undefined) {
       if (newShape.type === google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON) {
       var path = newShape.getPaths().getAt(e.path);
       path.removeAt(e.vertex);
       if (path.length < 3) {
        newShape.setMap(null);
      }
     }
     if (newShape.type === google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE) {
      var path = newShape.getPath();
      path.removeAt(e.vertex);
       if (path.length < 2) {
       newShape.setMap(null);
       }
      }
      }
      setSelection(newShape);
      });
     }
    var coords = e.overlay.getPath().getArray();
    console.log("POLY:" + coords.toString());
    var div = document.getElementById('info');
    div.innerHTML += "[" + coords + "]";
  });
 }
```

**HTML**

```
<%= hidden_field_tag(:map_coords, value = nil, html_options = {id: 'info'}) %>
<div id="map"></div>
```

**Property controller**

```
def create
    @property = Property.new(property_params)
    @property.coordinates = params[:map_coords]

    respond_to do |format|
      if @property.save
        format.html { redirect_to @property, notice: 'Property was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @property }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @property.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

**Schema**

```
create_table "properties", force: :cascade do |t| 
 t.string "name"
 t.json "coordinates"
 t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
end
```

Comment: Can you post the full code for your ``create`` controller method and what parameters you are permitting on the controller?

Comment: I have posted the full create method. Standard method really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like rmlockerd said, make sure you permitted the parameters in your controller:

`params.require(:property).permit(map_coords: [])`

I think storing them as an array is not great, you should send them as a hash and transform them to json. (jsonb if you are using PSQL is more efficient)

Also, in your JS, you are not setting the value of your hidden field tag to anything, your are just adding HTML to it. You should set the coords to the `value()` of the field.

Comment: Thanks @askprod. Spot on, I forgot to add the require parameters and value. I had :map_coords instead of map_coords: [] and set the value in javascript to be accepted into the hidden_field_tag.